# "I am angry to die" or "I am angry to death"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, nouns

I want to say that I may die because I am angry.

Can I say "I am angry to die" or "I am angry to death" to express the above?

Comment: I am so angry I could die. My anger is killing me

Comment: In spite of absurd meaning, I mean "I am angry to die"is right expression or not.

Comment: It may not be idiomatic, but I do not see anything wrong with "I am angry to death" in the sense you wanted. However, "I am angry to die" is not the right phrase as it conveys a different meaning.

Comment: Then, I want to know the meaning of " I am angry to die."

Comment: "I am angry to die" would mean something more along the lines of "I am angry that I'm about to die." That's something a cancer patient might say on a deathbed.  You want to say, "I am angry to death," which means, "I'm so angry that I could just about die from my anger."

Comment: @박용현: No, "I am angry to die" expresses the reverse relation: Not death from anger, but anger at imminent death.

Comment: In Elvis's own words, "you get me so lonely baby, I get so lonely, I get so lonely I could die."

Comment: @박용현 mplungjan already explained to you the correct way to say this in English. Neither of the two examples you've posted would sound normal to a native English speaker.

Comment: I'd agree that if you parse "I am angry to die", the logical meaning is "I am angry about the idea that I must die". But I think it's an awkward sentence. I think most English speakers would be more likely to say "I am angry that I am going to die" or some such. "I am angry to death" might mean "I am so angry that it will cause my death." But it's an unclear sentence. I wouldn't use it. Express the idea another way.

Comment: Couldn't you just say... I'm dead-angry.

Comment: Neither of these sentences makes much sense to a native speaker. We don't say things like "I'm angry to die" or "I'm angry to death". They sound like something a child would say, and then we'd ask the child to explain himself. We would understand that he was angry, but we wouldn't understand the death reference. I think what you *actually* want to say is "I am so angry that I could just die."  However, even that is a little strange. In English, we don't relate anger to death in that way. Death is more correlated with things like sleep, so it seems odd to say "I'm so angry I could just die."

Answer (score 8):

Your first choice of "I am angry to die" does not convey what you want to mean. It means that you are angry that you are dying.

One idiomatic way is to use the construction

> I am so X I could Y.

X is an adjective (or adjective phrase) and Y is a verb phrase.

For example

> I'm so hungry I could eat a horse.

Where X is *hungry* and Y is *eat a horse*.

So for your example that would be

> I am so angry I could die.

Your second choice, "I am angry to death", is OK, but I don't think most people would use it.

Comment: Matt, I heard "I'm hungry as hell" too. Could you please confirm?

Comment: Yes, @Carlo_R., that is a saying.

Comment: @Carlo_R. "I'm hungry as hell" is not in the same league -- it doesn't mean "I am so hungry, I want to go to hell" or something.

Answer (score 5):

Americans like my mother say things like *I'm **sick to death** of your moaning!* I've never heard *I'm angry to death*. It's understandable but not idiomatic. People don't die of anger unless they have a stroke or a heart attack because of it (Type A personality people sometimes do). So I'd suggest you not use it.

*I'm angry to die* means that you're unhappy about the fact that you're about to die, so unhappy, in fact, that you're angry about it and want to curse God and whoever or whatever else might have caused your probably premature death. I don't think it's the right expression in this context. That should probably be *I'm angry about dying (too soon / so soon / so young / for nothing / because I caught a cold / etc.)*.

> Heartbreak Hotel (Elvis Presley)
>
> Well, since my baby left me
>   I found a new place to dwell
>   It's down at the end of lonely street
>   At heartbreak hotel
>
> You make me so lonely, baby
>   **I get so lonely, I get so lonely, I could die**

Answer (score 4):

"Angry to death" exists in literature, though not much used today. To that extent, "I am angry to death" is grammatically and semantically acceptable to mean "I am so angry, I could die."

> Then God speaks again to Jonah: “Is it good and right for you to be angry about the vine?” This time Jonah replies with words and he asserts himself violently, “I am right! I am angry enough to die!” Literally, “**I am angry to death**.”  [Emphasis mine]

(Dr. Wes Bredenhof [God is Right to Care](http://www.theseed.info/sermon.php?id=306))

> The poor man also had a friend called Abinuku — **he is angry to death** — who hated everybody in his heart, but did not show it in his face. [Emphasis mine]

([Culture, Politics & Money Among the Yoruba - Page 54](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=KxL03_ajZNgC&pg=PA54&dq=%22angry%20to%20death%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OYSrUJadEoLtrQep_ICwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22angry%20to%20death%22&f=false))

---

[EDIT]
I would say, though, the context better be so as to make the meaning amply clear. Somewhat like in the examples.

Comment: I think it is true that it is acceptable, but the user should be prepared to explain more fully what is meant. I would expect a lot of people (the majority?) to ask for clarification.

Comment: It may be "technically" correct, but in terms of modern usage, especially in a normal conversation, it would cause the people you were with to pause.

Comment: @horatio Edited in a rider!

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Edited in a rider!

Answer (score 1):

No. Matt Ellen has given the usual idiom, but has not addressed your samples.

> I am angry to die.

can only mean *I am angry (about the fact) that I will die/am dying*.

> I am angry to death.

*could* mean what you say, but it does not exist as an idiom. There is an idiom *sick to death*, but note that it does not mean *sick* in its main sense, but only in the sense of *fed up*, i.e. *suffering because something has happened too many times*. Note also that there is no literal contemplation of *death* in this idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Since your example "I am angry to die" has caused so much dissension amongst the users of this site, it would probably also confuse your readers.  Why not use another expression that expresses the same degree of anger but is more readily understood such as:

I am furious!

I am ready to blow my top!

I am mad as hell!

I am so mad I could kill!

AAAAAAARRGGGHHH!

Comment: As in most cases, questions *do not* include options for alternatives. OP only asks "Can I say...". And, at least theoretically, yes, he can.

Answer (score -1):

"Angry enough to die" expresses a sullen inward anger rather than a violent anger.  It is depressive anger, without hope of changing things outwardly.  It is the anger of the self-absorbed.  Cf. Jonah from the bible.

Comment: Like depression?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and your submission does not appear to attempt to answer the original question. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.