# "I am full to die." — Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, infinitives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I am angry to die” or “I am angry to death”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91796/i-am-angry-to-die-or-i-am-angry-to-death)

> I am full to die.

I meant to say, "I might die because I am full."

Is this a correct expression?

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense,this is better :I am full of regret and waiting to die

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't correct. I'm assuming that your sentence means that you've eaten far too much dinner, that you've got a serious stomachache, and that you don't want to stick your finger down your throat to relieve the pain, and that therefore you want to die. I felt that way when I gave myself alcohol poisoning one New Year's Eve.

You might want to say *I'm so full that I might die*.

Answer (score 2):

Google finds just three examples of this phrase, two in a blog and one in a Chinese site. In these cases it seems to mean "I am so full I could die", or more idiomatically, "I am full to bursting."

"I am full to die" is not grammatical these days; the construction is at best archaic and may be obsolete ("I am angry to die" = "I am so angry I could die").

*Full to* needs a noun — *to* is a preposition. Something can be *full to the top, full to overflowing* (*overflowing* is a gerund), *full to bursting*.

Comment: I'd interpret it as grammatical, if somewhat poetic in the phrasing, and meaning that the person was fully ready to die, to the point of welcoming it.